# Prove that the integral operator has no eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real valued continuous functions. Prove that the linear operator $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ has no eigenvalues.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Have you tried anything?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$T$ has no eigen-values](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813879/t-has-no-eigen-values)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Suppose that $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^*$ is an eigenvalue of this operator associated to the eigenvector $f \neq 0$. Then, for all $x$, you have :

$$ \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \: dt = \lambda f(x) $$

with the condition that $f(0)=0$. If you differentiate the previous equality, you have $f(x) = \lambda f'(x)$ with $f(0) = 0$. You can easily solve the differential equation $f = \lambda f'$ but the only solution which satisfies $f(0)=0$ is the function $x \, \mapsto \, 0$.

Comment: Why $f(0) = 0$ ?

Comment: @RisingStar : An eigenvector $f$ satisfies the relation :

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt = \lambda f(x) $$

with $\lambda \neq 0$. Evaluate this at $x=0$.

Comment: Actually why you have taken $\lambda$ to be non zero ?

Comment: @RisingStar : The case $\lambda = 0$ is quite straightforward. An eigenvector $f$ associated to $\lambda = 0$ would satisfy :

$$ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}, \, \int_{0}^{x} f(t) \, dt = 0 $$

As a consequence, $f \equiv 0$, which is not possible since an eigenvector is not identically zero.

Comment: what do you mean by f is similar to 0? or you meant f=0?

Comment: @jamesblack: $f \equiv 0$ means that $f$ is the null function (equal to 0 everywhere).

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Suppose you have $\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt = \lambda \cdot f(t)$. Differentiate both sides - you should easily be able to solve the resultant differential equation. Is your solution truly an eigenvector if it is nontrivial?

Comment: You can't differentiate $f$ as it is assumed to be only continuous.

Comment: @Marra: there is no assumption that $f$ is differentiable. The LHS is differentiable, and so too must be $\lambda f(t)$. This is a *consequence* of $f$ being an eigenvector.

Comment: Indeed! But for that you must assume that $f$ is an eigenvector. thanks!