# Integral operator has no eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, integral-operators

Let $V$ be the vector space of all real valued continuous functions. Prove that the linear operator $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt$ has no eigenvalues.
This question is same as
[Prove that the integral operator has no eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455695/prove-that-the-integral-operator-has-no-eigenvalues)
However i am not able to understand why $f(0)=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that
$$
\displaystyle\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt=\lambda f(x),
$$
then we can differentiate both sides:
$$
f(x)=\lambda f'(x)\\
\frac{\lambda df}{f}=dx\\
\lambda\ln|f|=x+C.
$$
Also,
$$
f(0)=\int_{0}^{0}f(t)dt=0.
$$

So, $\lambda\ln|0|= C$ which is impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Because if $f$ is an eigenvector of that operator with an eigenvalue $\lambda\neq0$, then$$\int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm dt=\lambda f(x)$$and therefore$$0=\int_0^0f(t)\,\mathrm dt=\lambda f(0),$$which implies that $f(0)=0$.